# Change ImageView source in specific page in ViewPager Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, fragment, adapter

I want to change imageresource in specific page in view pager. This is what i've done.

This is onCreate activity ...

```
        ((PlaceholderFragment)mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0)).updateImage(R.drawable.help1);
        ((PlaceholderFragment)mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1)).updateImage(R.drawable.help2);
        ((PlaceholderFragment)mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2)).updateImage(R.drawable.help3);
        ((PlaceholderFragment)mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(3)).updateImage(R.drawable.help4);
```

And this is the fragment class...

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageHelp);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.help4);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void updateImage(int image){
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageHelp);
        imageView.setImageResource(image);

    }
}
```

But somehow it still give me error null pointer exception. How do I miss ?
Thanks before and please help me :) Im stuck here for about 2 hours.

Comment: show your logcat as well which line it shows null pointer exception.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Cause by line ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// declare rootView as global variable

public void updateImage(int image){
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageHelp);
    imageView.setImageResource(rootView);
}
```

Comment: I do it, make rootView global, but somehow it still give me error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference